# how to disable tooltip in angular based on condition

Tags: angular, typescript

How do we implement conditional tool tip ? , for example I only wanna show tool tip if cellData[id].length>120 on a div element

#code

```
<div matTooltip="Info about the action" class="{{cssCell}}">{{(cellData[id].length>120)? (cellData[id] | slice:0:120)+'..':(cellData[id]) }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matTooltipDisabled` for this:

```
<div
  matTooltip="Info about the action"
  [matTooltipDisabled]="cellData[id].length <= 120"
  class="{{cssCell}}"
>
  {{(cellData[id].length>120)? (cellData[id] | slice:0:120)+'..':(cellData[id]) }}
</div>
```